# How to edit the text that was already written to console with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

For example, robocopy will display the percentage of a file that is being copied. The percentage will change without the need to write more output to the console. How can I emulate the same behavior, where text that was already written to the console gets modified?

Comment: Use `Write-Host` `\`r` for newline and `\`b` for backspace. You can also output without a terminating newline using the `-NoNewLine` parameter.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart So I'm guessing in the example with robocopy, they count the number of characters they wrote, then they `b that number of times, then rewrite the line with the new percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer can be shortened thus:

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
Write-Host -NoNewLine "$text`r"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Write-Host -NoNewLine ("`b" * $text.Length)
Write-Host "consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this. It uses `$host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition` to determine where the console text is currently writing and manipulating that to 
overwrite previously written text.

**Simple Test**

I have adapted your "Lorem ipsum" example to use `$host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition`.

```psh
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
$origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
Write-Host $text -NoNewLine
Start-Sleep -s 4
$host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
Write-Host "consectetur adipiscing elit"
```

The following example will cycle the characters in `$scroll` giving the impression of a rotating line. All this does is run a sleep command for 10 seconds. Depending on your needs you would obviously not need to run *all* this code.

```psh
$scroll = "/-\|/-\|"
$idx = 0
$job = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:ComputerName -ScriptBlock { Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 } -AsJob

$origpos = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
$origpos.Y += 1

while (($job.State -eq "Running") -and ($job.State -ne "NotStarted"))
{
    $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
    Write-Host $scroll[$idx] -NoNewline
    $idx++
    if ($idx -ge $scroll.Length)
    {
        $idx = 0
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
# It's over - clear the activity indicator.
$host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $origpos
Write-Host 'Complete'
```

**Caveat:** Both this and the test will not work as intended in ISE. Also if not used correctly your cursor can end up in a weird place after.

Answer (score 0):

Full credit goes to @Bill_Stewart for this answer.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
Write-Host $text -NoNewLine
Start-Sleep -s 2
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $text.Length; $i++){
    Write-Host `b -NoNewLine
}
Write-Host "consectetur adipiscing elit"
```